# How to add the name of my organization to a Mozilla Public License?

Tags: licensing, mpl, ownership

My organization made a Python module and would like to share it under the Mozilla Public License.

Is there a way to add the name of this organization to the license ?

If I use the license as is, there is no name at all. But according to [the FAQ of the MPL](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/FAQ/):

> Q4 : I want to use the Mozilla Public License for software that I have
>   written. What do I have to do?
>
> To apply the Mozilla Public License to software that you have written, add the header from Exhibit A of the license to each source code file in your project. Sample headers for various commenting styles are available here. **You may also add additional accurate notices of copyright ownership, such as the name of the copyright holder, but this is not necessary.**

But this answer does not really indicates how to do it in the license file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although many people believe that lines like `copyright 2018, Bart van Ingen Schenau` are part of the license, legally they are not. Those lines are notices of copyright ownership (or copyright notice) and they declare who owns the copyright on the work.

A copyright notice consists of the word "copyright" followed by a list of years and/or ranges of years and finally a list of copyright owners.

The common practice is to have the copyright notices directly preceding the license text (or a formal reference to the license), with the two separated by a blank line.